# python and string slicing using literals?

Tags: python

```
an_letters = "aefhilmnorsxAEFHILMNORSX"
word = input("I will cheer for you! enter a word:")
times = int(input("Enthusiasm level (1-10):"))
i = 0
while i < len(word):
    char = word[i]
    if char in an_letters:
        print("Give ma an " + char + "! " + char)
    else:
        print("Give ma a " + char + "! " + char)
    i += 1
print("What does that spell?")
for i in range(times):
    print(word, "!!!!")
```

I'm struggling to understand what `char = word[i]` does. Afaik there's no `char` type in Python, only `str` I assume this is simply an variable and it does indexing on the variable `word`. But I don't understand what is the `i` referring to? Shouldn't we use numbers to indicate the position ?

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't we use numbers to indicate the position ?

Umm... `i = 0`... It is a number! And it is not slicing here. It's indexing. Strings are Iterable like lists

Though that while looping is not Pythonic and the `i` is never actually used in the loop. You could rewrite that

```
for char in word:
    if char in an_letters:
```

Answer (score 1):

`Char` is just a variable, you give it any other name... then `char` will take the sub-string character contain in `word` for each iteration for example if `word="hello"` `word[1]="h"`, `word[2]="e"`...

`[i]` is the index, the position in `word`